# Adding a left bar button item when in edit mode of tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

How can I impose additional behavior when in the edit mode of a table view controller. I want to implement a behavior just like the Recents section of Phone application where once Edit is pressed a Clear button appears on the left. How can I do this?

In viewDidLoad I have

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

And therefore when Edit button is pressed I get the red circles that gives me the deleting capability which works fine and then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called automatically so the tableview and the underlying data is updated. They all work fine. But if I modify the content of viewDidLoad like the following

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = @selector(editPressed:);
```

and implement

```
- (IBAction)editPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"In Edit Pressed");
}
```

Pressing Edit button will take me to editPressed: but now the normal behavior of Edit for tableview is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the default view controller edit button, you can override the method `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` of the `UITableViewController`. So, you can put the code in this method, and `super` it. So, your code could look like this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (myTable.editing)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = additionalButtonItem;
    else
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried what you suggested and refined my question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I editing my original answer; You don't need the IBAction, and this one should allow all of the normal behavior to be retained.

Comment: Thanks wquist! setEditing was the way!